# Entire function such that $f(z)=f(z+1)$ for all $z$, then f is constant?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

If $f$ is entire function such that $f(z)=f(z+1)$ for all $z$ is not that enough to consider that $f$ is constant. Why? Because we have $f(0)=f(1)=f(2)=\cdots$ and then $f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+2)=\cdots$ so the function $f$ is determined by the image of points in the unit desk but $f$ is bounded in the unit desk no poles since it is entire so by Liouville’s theorem $f$ is a constant? 
Is there something missing! Am I correct

In fact the original question give another condition $f(z)=f(z+1)=f(z+a)$ for an irrational $a$ to figure out that $f$ is a constant.

Comment: There are non constant periodic functions which are entire.  $e^z$, for instance.  Having two incommensurable periods is a different matter.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's the reason that non-constant elliptic functions cannot be holomorphic, for example.

Comment: Just to stress:  $f(z)=e^{2\pi i z}$ is an entire function satisfying $f(z)=f(z+1)$.  You really do need that second condition.

Comment: @lulu  aha I see I think I missed when I said $f$ is determined by the image of the unit desk

Comment: Well,  a single period just means the function is determined by its values on an infinite strip.  As that's unbounded, there is no contradiction.  The unit disk doesn't enter into this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f$ is constant on the set $C=\{m+na\,|\,m,n\in\mathbb Z\}$; it is equal to $f(0)$ in each element of $C$. But $\overline C=\mathbb R$ and $f$ is continuous. So, the restriction of $f$ to $\mathbb R$ is constant. It follows from the identity theorem that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Sure I am! If $f(z)=\sin(2\pi z)$, then $f$ is entire and $(\forall z\in\mathbb C):f(z+1)=f(z)$, but $f$ is not constant.

Comment: So my argument is not correct! $f$ is not determined by the image of the unit desk right?

Comment: Another question why the closure of the set $C$ is $\mathbb{R}$ the interval $(a/2-e,a/2+e)$ where $e$ is very small have empty intersection with $C$

Comment: Yes, the function *is* determined by its restriction to the unit disk. But it doesn't follow from this that $f$ is bounded.

Comment: What makes you think that, if $\varepsilon$ is small enough, then $\left(\frac a2-\varepsilon,\frac a2+\varepsilon\right)\cap C=\emptyset$? That is not true. Actually that intersection is an infinite set.

Comment: $n,m$ are integers not rationals that’s why

Comment: And… ? Take $a=\sqrt{\frac12}$, for instance. Then $24-34a\approx-0.0416306$, $29-41a\approx0.00862197$, $19-27a\approx-0.0918831$, and so on…